# How to filter edit text from a firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code from which I get the text:

```
etSearchFriends = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchFriends);


        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                searchText = etSearchFriends.getText().toString();
                filterLocation(searchText);
            }
        });
```

Here's the filter where code should work but sadly it isn't:

```
private void filterLocation(final String s) {
    final ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("UserData1",s);

    fRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                fname = dataSnapshot1.child("fname").getValue(String.class);
            }
                for (User user1 : ListOfBranches.getUsers()) {
                    if (fname.toLowerCase().contains(s)) {
                        users.add(user1);
                        Log.d("UserData3", dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                    }
                }
                friendsAdapter.filterLocation(users);


        }
```

While this is the list where another data is fetched from database:

```
    userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserFiture");

        userRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//                User user1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                User u = new User();
                String fname = dataSnapshot.child("fName").getValue(String.class);
                String lname = dataSnapshot.child("lName").getValue(String.class);
                String age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                String gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue(String.class);

                u.setfName(fname);
                u.setlName(lname);
                u.setAge(age);
                u.setGender(gender);
                users.add(u);
                Log.e("dataSnapshot", String.valueOf(u));
            }
```

I want to get all the data here and show it if search text is equals to fname:
[image]

Comment: What is your final goal? You basically want to filter users where `fName` is "Deceree"?

Comment: Firebase data fetching is asynchronous that means your method `ListOfBranches.getUsers()` will be executing in a separate thread and the main thread wont wait for your response. That will result in List of user being null or empty in almost every case.

Comment: @AlexMamo yes basically

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez what should i do?

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055319/search-firebasedatabase-for-users-by-username/55063485#55063485) a few minytes ago. Take a look at it.

Comment: can you please define what `fRef` points to ?

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez fRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserFiture");